# Javascript on reload how to display the existing page untill new page is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using to javascript `location.reload()` `fn` to reload the page.
It is working fine but as soon as this function is called existing page went and waits for the new page to load. switching from old to new screen there is a delay. Users can see a blank screen. can anyone suggest any solution?

I'm thinking of delaying the old screen until new screen is loaded and ready. If that is a good option,tell me how to stay on the existing page ?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Use ajax: load content and add it on success

Comment: @Zword: can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using `location.reload()`. A similar effect could be achieved by doing an ajax request and then replacing the entire body content with the new content.

Something such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#replace').click(function () {
        $('#the-content').load('mynewpage.html');
    });
});
```

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ExJz4/ for a not really working example.

Also check out the `$.load()` documentation https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "page.php", /*page which is to be loaded*/
 data: "",  /*send data if any*/
 success: function(msg){
        $('body').html(msg); /*add new content to body*/
 },
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Some error occured"); /*error message*/
 }
 });
```

### ***[jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)***